# How can I consume an SQL Azure database from an ASP.NET API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, azure

I'm creating an API meant to consume data on an exiting SQL Azure database. I'm creating this API based on ASP.NET's Web API 2.

I'm a complete newbie on this area. This is why I've been following ASP.NET tutorials. I'm able to create a Web API and create models/controllers. But on the database side, every tutorial I come across is about creating a database from the scratch dedicated for the API, not about connecting an existing database that is consumed by the API.

How can I make the connection and query the database from the API?

**Tutorials I've followed**

- Using Web API 2 with Entity Framework 6: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1
- Create a REST service using ASP.NET Web API and SQL Database in Azure App Service: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database/

Comment: Check for database `connectionString` and try reading about how to use that `connectionString` to consume database..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Login to the Windows Azure management portal
2. Click on **"SQL DATABASES"** in the menu
3. Click on the database you want to connect to
4. Right at the bottom click on **"View SQL Database connection strings for ADO .Net, ODBC, PHP, and JDBC"**
5. Copy the connection from the **"ADO.NET"** text box and change the password to the valid password.
6. Now in your WEB API project open the .config file and paste the connection string in the designated element:

**Connection string:**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyAzzureConnection" connectionString="paste the connection string from Azure here" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now you can write your data access code using the technology of your choice, just make sure you use the Azure connection from the Web.config file.

Comment: Could you please fix the broken link?